# Possible to improve dbeaver UX / reduce number of clicks needed?

Tags: user-experience, dbeaver

Is it possible to make dbeaver easier to use just by customizing the settings in the application? I searched through all the settings pages but there didn't seem to be much there.

Specifically, it takes far too many clicks to open up tables after I first open dbeaver.

Here's a screenshot of the dbeaver tree for a db connection I have open:
[image]

When I first open the dbeaver program, the tree is completely closed, so it takes 5 clicks on the caret icons to expand to the actual tables finally, and then I have to double click on the table that I then want to open.
This takes up far too much mental burden than necessary especially when I'm in a flow and open up dbeaver to inspect the data in a table, and I have to slow down just to navigate the tree to the tables.

Now, compare this to this other database browser called Postico:
[image]

In this application, there are no extra clicks! The program opens to this screen by default where all the tables are listed on the left side, and it only takes one click to open any table. This has literally reduced the number of clicks just to open a table from dbeaver's 7 to just 1!

I would just Postico all the time as it's far faster and simpler to use, but there are certain advanced features in dbeaver that I need to use sometimes as well so I'd rather make dbeaver work for me all the time.

So that's the kind of smoothness that I'd like to emulate in dbeaver. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Window > Preferences > User Interface > Navigator > Miscellaneous > ✅ Expand navigator tree on connect.

   [image: Expand navigator tree on connect]
2. Right click on a connection > Connection view > Simple

   [image: Simple connection view]

Comment: Oh wow, I had tried the Expand Navigator option before but it only expanded the first node before. I tried again this time but also set the depth option to a higher number and that fixed it! 
I didn't know about #2: the connection view though - this helped a lot. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is a big improvement. However when misspelling a table name the table list is empty, and doesn't reopen when correcting the table name. You have to click to open the database to see the filtered list. So I'm taking real good care to make no mistakes to avoid the extra click